# How do I separate this two menus on gnome (pop os)

Tags: gnome, pop-os

How do I separate the audio popup from the default system one? is there a way? sorry if I am phrasing this badly, but I couldn't find anything online and English is not my first language.

[image: Pop os menu]

Comment: The image shows what is called the System Menu. Natively, there is no option in Gnome to move the audio options in the System Menu to a separate menu (I think that's what you're looking to achieve?). Your best bet is probably to search for "audio" on the Gnome extensions website (https://extensions.gnome.org/). There might be an extension that does what you want.